# Add placeholder in JSON string in React

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**My JSON:**

```
{
  "error" :"{len} is min length"
}
```

I want to display in GUI "10 is the min length" from the function where I am getting the JSON. Is there a way I can pass `{len}` dynamically when accessing `JSON.error`

Comment: `error.replace('{len}', 10)` not good enough?

Comment: @Sagivb.g i didn't knew that was an option.  Let me try

Answer (score 0):

A simple [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can do the job:

```js
const response = {
  "error" :"{len} is min length"
};

const length = 10;
const result = response.error.replace('{len}', length);
console.log(result);
```